# Sync error between windows server AD and Azure AD

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2019, entra-id

I have windows server 2019 OS with AD synced to Azure AD via Azure AD connect sync.

I recently changed my domain @mydomain for some of my old users. Unfortunately, I also erroneously changed the domain for the user that synchronises between AD and Azure AD. Later, I reverted back the change from @mydomain to @Istit.omnimicrosoft.com.
On office365 (Azure AD) control panel the sync status of password is green while the sync status for directory is red (the synchronisation account is correct and there are not errors under control panel->settings->directory sync errors).

I tried to run [IDfix](https://github.com/microsoft/idfix), there are not any errors.
On local AD, the Azure AD connect reports some errors [image: attacched]. In particular, there is a common error sync-generic-failure with stack trace:

```
GetAttribute(): Attribute extension_ebca89ec5199450f860137ded21a1394_accountExpires not found in schema with GUID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 

   in Microsoft.IdentityManagement.PowerShell.ObjectModel.Schema.GetAttribute(String name)
   in Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.SyncRulesEngine.AttributeFlowModule.PerformAttributeFlowMappingFlow(IEnumerable`1 annotatedAttributeFlowMappings, IEntryModification targetObject)
   in Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.SyncRulesEngine.AttributeFlowModule.PerformSyncRuleAttributeFlows(IEntryModification sourceObject, IEntryModification targetObject, SynchronizationRule synchronizationRule, Boolean applyExecuteOnceMappings)
   in Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.SyncRulesEngine.JoinModule.PerformAttributeFlowForAllSourceLinks(SyncRulePipelineArguments pipelineArguments, IEntryModification sourceObject, IEnumerable`1 syncRulesJustApplied, AttributeFlowModule attributeFlowModule)
   in Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.SyncRulesEngine.JoinModule.Execute(PipelineArguments argsToProcess)
   in Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.SyncRulesEngine.Server.SyncEngine.RunSyncPipeline(SyncRulePipelineArguments pipelineData, List`1 pipelineChain)
   in Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.SyncRulesEngine.Server.SyncEngine.RunOutboundWithRecall(SyncRulePipelineArguments pipelineData)
   in Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.SyncRulesEngine.Server.SyncEngine.Synchronize(SynchronizationOperation operation, IObjectLinkGraph inputGraph, Boolean preview)
   in ManagedSyncRulesEngine.Synchronize(ManagedSyncRulesEngine* , CCsObject* sourceCsObject, CMvObject* mvObject, SynchronizationOperation operation, Char** error)


InnerException=>
none 

Native call stack:
```

I searched a lot on the Web without finding a solution. Do you have any idea?

Thank you

Comment: Open a support case from your Office 365 tenant. It's free. They'll help you resolve this issue.

Comment: Thank you, I did it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a (trivial) solution. I just upgraded the AD Azure connect software from 1.4.18 to 2.0.28. I didn't think to do this before, but it worked fine until a week ago.